# SQL Text data type deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, sql-standard

I have read that Microsoft SQL Server has deprecated the `text` data type in favour of `varchar(max)`.

PostGreSQL already allows `varchar` (without a length) as an alternative for `text`.

The question is, what does the ANSI SQL standard have to say about deprecating `text`, and the best alternative? Also, does MySQL/MariaDB also follow this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I know that SQL Server isn’t fully ANSI compliant. The question is what does the ANSI standard have to say about the TEXT data type?

Comment: Does anybody know if SQL has informed the public which version of SQL Server will remove the TEXT data type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the ANSI SQL Standard, there is no `TEXT` type. There are various string types defined, like `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` and many more but no mention of a `TEXT` type. There is a `CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT` and a `BINARY LARGE OBJECT`.

The various `TEXT` types found in various DBMS (Postgres, SQL Server, MySQL) are additions and have small differences between them. Their similarity is that they can hold very large strings.

SQL Server's `TEXT` is being deprecated. MySQL's `TEXT` is not deprecated. PostgreSQL's `TEXT` is well supported and recommended by many to be used everywhere, in place of `VARCHAR(n)`. From Postgres documentation, [Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html):

> In addition, PostgreSQL provides the text type, which stores strings of any length. Although the **type `text` is not in the SQL standard**, several other SQL database management systems have it as well.

So, the questions:

> The question is, what does the ANSI SQL standard have to say about deprecating `text`, and the best alternative? Also, does MySQL/MariaDB also follow this?

are simple to answer: Nothing and No. There is no deprecation of `TEXT` as there is no `TEXT` type. `TEXT` isn't even a reserved keyword in ANSI SQL. One DBMS (MySQL) does not have to follow another DBMS's (SQL Server) deprecation decisions for a type that isn't in the standard.

Comment: Thanks. That’s the answer I was looking for — information about `TEXT` rather than information about SQL Server. I also note that PostgreSQL appears to prefer `varchar` (no length) to `text`. Of the popular databases I am aware that MySQL is furthest from ANSI in many respects.

Comment: `text` is slightly more efficient than `varchar` in Postgres. I think there was an answer in the site, by @Erwin, explaining why. All DBMS have differences with the standard but Postgres is one that has implemented many syntax features. I'd say it's the one closest to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL standard (which I assume you refer to) will nothing to say on how Microsoft (or Oracle, etc) implement and remove data types to suit their particular flavour of DBMS, and which ones take precedence.

The Microsoft standard is to use varchar in place of text, nvarchar in place of ntext, and varbinary in place of image, and this is because of the improved capabilities/performance of the data types and how it is stored in the database.

Here's a related StackOverflow question and answer that should give you more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564755/sql-server-text-type-vs-varchar-data-type

**Update**

This is as close as you're going to get to reading the standard without buying it. You're interested in section **4.4.3.2 Character String types**

http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1951-2000/32N1963T-text_for_ballot-FCD_9075-1.pdf

As I said earlier - the standard has no bearing on how anyone deprecates a data type, nor anything about **specific** data types. Just what **a** type itself should conform to.

I've also found that the PDF I've linked to can be found on the SQL:2011 Wiki page (which I assume you've checked before asking this question) :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011

Comment: Besides your links, check these ones from the question: [Obtaining gratis copy of the SQL specification?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/778/obtaining-gratis-copy-of-the-sql-specification) and this site: [Don't Tell Anyone: The SQL Standard is Public!](https://modern-sql.com/standard)

Comment: Regarding that *"nothing to say"*, taken from the SQL standard: *"SQL defines predefined data types named by the following <key word>s:
CHARACTER
CHARACTER VARYING
CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT
BINARY
BINARY VARYING
BINARY LARGE OBJECT
NUMERIC
DECIMAL
SMALLINT
INTEGER
BIGINT
FLOAT
REAL
DOUBLE PRECISION
BOOLEAN
DATE
TIME
TIMESTAMP
INTERVAL"*